# error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "test.local": lookup test.local on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-route53, kops

I am new to aws ec2. My task is to create a test kubernetes cluster using kops. So, I followed the document that provided by the aws in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/kubernetes-clusters-aws-kops/ . These are the steps i followed as per the documentation:

1) aws s3api create-bucket --bucket kops-test --region ap-south-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=ap-south-1

2) aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket kops-test --region ap-south-1 --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled

3) export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://kops-test

4) ID=$(uuidgen) && aws route53 create-hosted-zone --name test.local --caller-reference $ID | jq .DelegationSet.NameServers

5) ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "TestKey" -f ~/.ssh/test-key

6) aws ec2 import-key-pair --key-name "test_kops_key" --public-key-material file://~/.ssh/test-key.pub

7) kops create cluster --name kops.test.local --zones ap-south-1a --master-size t2.micro --node-size t2.micro --kubernetes-version 1.16.0

8) kops create secret --name kops.test.local sshpublickey admin -i ~/.ssh/test-key.pub

9) kops update cluster --name kops.test.local --yes

At first when i executed the step 7 initially, I got this error:
**SSH public key must be specified when running with AWS (create with `kops create secret --name kops.test.local sshpublickey admin -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)**

So I executed the step 8. And it was successful. Then to initiate the cluster, I executed the step 9, then I got the below error:
**error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "test.local": lookup test.local on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host**

Do I need to add the route53 hosted zone with the name only in the actual DNS server? Can't we add a hosted zone with any name like in the above?

I'm lost at this point & i tried many articles, but could not solve this issue. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Did you run step 7 ?

Comment: yes, and i got this:
 SSH public key must be specified when running with AWS (create with kops create secret --name kops.test.local sshpublickey admin -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

Comment: after running step 8 run step 7 again. did you see same?

Comment: you could just use EKS instead https://aws.amazon.com/eks/getting-started/

Comment: @Vorsprung: my project may run on different cloud service. since eks is possible only for the aws, it's not good for me now.

Comment: @hoque: cluster "kops.test.local" already exists; use 'kops update cluster' to apply changes --- this is what i got. that's why i executed step 9.

Comment: ....but KOPS only runs on AWS.  Presumably your are only interested in the kubernetes API and not the stuff underneath it.  Good luck!

Comment: @RINSHEEDHUSSAIN delete the cluster created at step 7 and try again running step 7

Comment: @hoque: Yeah.. i deleted the cluster using 'kops delete' command. Then executed the step 7, and i got the same error as before.

Comment: @hoque: Do I need to add the route53 hosted zone with the name only in the actual DNS server? Can't we add a hosted zone with any name like in the above?

Comment: According to the documentation you may need to create route53 dns for your cluster. details https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kops/#2-5-create-a-route53-domain-for-your-cluster

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the issue at last. The Route53 hosted zone which I created was not pointed correctly to the DNS. So, I imported the zone file of my domain to the Route53 hosted zone, & updated the name servers of the domain with the name servers that generated in the Route53 hosted zone.

Comment: Can you please add additional details to how you solved the problem.